# Video background change by difference

Tags: node-editor, transparency

How to remove background in video if i have background picture?

I use node editor. Image is clickable 1280x720. Video screenshot + background
[image: Video screenshot]
[image: Background]

I tried to use mask and chromakey, but result is bad

[image: My try]

Comment: my advise is to re-do the whole thing so that your scene works with a proper chroma key. For starters get an iron and get rid of the wrinkles, the flatter and more uniform the background is the easier it is to have a successful key. Then work a bit on your lighting. The background is lit very poorly.  On the left there is some daylight (or a bluish light source) and the character is lit with a yellowish one from the top that also contaminates the background. The goal is to have a very even background.

Comment: Something that will help you too is to move your subject away from the background so that the multiple shadows are not so much of an issue.

Comment: Also the lighting on your foreground subject doesn't even closely resemble the desert sunset image for the background.

Answer (score 6):

First I have to say, that key background is not very good. It needs to be  a very separate colour to skin and foreground (blue or green is best) and it should have NO shadows. Either from folds or from the foreground objects. An even flat plane of color is best.

You could try the [Keying screen Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/compositing/types/matte/keying_screen.html) derived by tracking marker samples or you could mix multiple keys to try and build a better key.
Here are a couple chroma keys added together with some erode node added to clean the mask up. Notice that I am using the colours of the foreground object, then I invert the matte to generate a key.

[image: Nodes]

I only have your sample frame to work with so it may fail during animation.

[image: result]

You would still have to use a tracked mask to clean up the holes in the foreground element. Good luck, you're really going to need it.

Answer (score 2):

### Difference Key

It could have been a work for Difference Key node (you can find it in the Matte section)

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/matte/difference_key.html)'s page:

> This node produces a matte that isolates foreground content by comparing it with a reference background image.

[image]

But you'll probably need to take advantage of other tricks within the compositor to isolate yourself properly. Or you can try to increase the contrast between the subject and the background (surely not casting a shadow upon it would help a lot)

Comment: Difference key is likely not going to work on compressed footage

Comment: @cegaton wouldn't work as good as depicted in the images above? I mean, those are two different frames of a (probably) compressed footage, infact there is some noise not depending on the presence of the subject.

Comment: Compression brings all kinds of variations from frame to frame

Comment: You could pre filter the A and B source before diff-ing them to try and alleviate the compression artefacts. But the shadow is still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best version I could accomplish with a Difference key as the OP wanted. I have had to add a couple of colour keys to improve the matte around the shadow from the foreground element.

[image: Diff key]

And here is the result. Perhaps some more colour keys would improve the shadow noise around the shoulder.

[image: Results]